# Stages based on a list on Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have something like this:

```
def projects = [
  "foo",
  "bar",
  "foobar",
  "etc",
]

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('lint') {
      parallel {
        stage('lint: foo') {
          steps {
            sh "lint foo"
          }
        }
        stage('lint: bar') {
          steps {
            sh "lint bar"
          }
        }
        stage('lint: foobar') {
          steps {
            sh "lint foobar"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I didn't really want to repeat myself there, is there a way I can "generate" the `stage` code for each project?

I was able to do something similar, without the `parallel` part with this:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('initialize') {
      steps {
        script {
          for (int i = 0; i < projects.size(); i++) {
            stage("lint: ${projects[i]}") {
              sh "lint ${project}"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Would be easy to achieve with scripted pipeline. Do you have to use declarative?

Comment: not really, don't know how scripted pipeline works.. will research. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scripted pipeline you may use something like:

```
def projects = [
  "foo",
  "bar",
  "foobar",
  "etc",
]

Map branches = [:]
projects.each { String project ->
    branches[project] = {
        stage(project) {
            node {
                // I assume we need to checkout something, e.g. using git or checkout step...
                // git ...
                sh "lint ${project}"
            }
        }
    }
}

parallel branches
```